# How do I stop my project from incorrectly being considered as "up to date"?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I've modified a .csproj project to append a task to BuildDependsOn. This performs a file copy. If the file copy fails, the build fails. (see XML below).

However, if I then 'build' again after a failed build attempt (in Visual Studio) Visual Studio reports that the project built successfully. It believes the project to be `up to date`.

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How do I ensure that this CopyFiles target runs on every build, to prevent this problem of VS reporting a successful build when a key stage in the build failed?

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MySourceFiles Include="$(TargetDir)*.dll;$(TargetDir)*.pdb"/>
</ItemGroup>


<Target Name="CopyFiles">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(DestFolder)\subfolder" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)AnotherFile.txt" DestinationFolder="$(DestFolder)" />
   <OnError ExecuteTargets="CopyFiles_Failed" />
</Target>
<Target Name="CopyFiles_Failed">
  <Error text="File copies failed">
  </Error>
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>
    $(BuildDependsOn);
    CopyFiles
  </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Is this just in your sample here that you depend on `CopyFilesToSDK` but your actual Target is named `CopyFiles`?

Comment: You could try adding the `SkipUnchangedFiles="false"` directive to your Copy Target to force it to execute.

Comment: I'll fix that - a typo. Also, the file copies are failing, so I don't think the file copies were successful so SkipUnchangedFiles="false" wouldnt make sense. But I'll give it a try!

Comment: Nope. VS reports the file copy failed. I guess I need to research how it decides if a project is up to date.

Comment: Maybe I need to make use of "Inputs" and "Outputs" of the target...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @maxkenir mentions, the [Inputs and Output parameter in a target define the set of files the build should check to decide whether it is up to date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx).

> ### Inputs
>
> The files that form inputs into this target. Multiple files are separated by semicolons. The timestamps of the files will be compared with the timestamps of files in Outputs to determine whether the Target is up to date. For more information, see Incremental Builds, How to: Build Incrementally, and MSBuild Transforms.
>
> ### Outputs
>
> The files that form outputs into this target. Multiple files are separated by semicolons. The timestamps of the files will be compared with the timestamps of files in Inputs to determine whether the Target is up to date. For more information, see Incremental Builds, How to: Build Incrementally, and MSBuild Transforms.

And the process to use them is further explained in the [article on Incremental Builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264087.aspx).

Basically it looks like thsi for a simple copy files action:

```
<Target Name="Backup" Inputs="@(files)" 
    Outputs="@(Compile->'$(BackupFolder)%(Identity).bak')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Compile)" DestinationFiles=
        "@(Compile->'$(BackupFolder)%(Identity).bak')" />
</Target>
```

More information on these [MsBuild transforms can be found again on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476.aspx), in your case it will probably be very close to:

```
<Target Name="CopyOutputs"
    Inputs="@(BuiltAssemblies)"
    Outputs="@(BuiltAssemblies -> '$(OutputPath)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">

    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(BuiltAssemblies)"
        DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)"/>

</Target>
```

But Inputs and Outputs will also [accept an Item Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx) and you can have multiple transforms as well.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like how to do it. Unfortunately, looking at that example, I have no idea how to cook up the syntax to do my specific copy job. I've updated the question to reflect more closely the actual situation. I would need to somehow generate the output file names from the input file names of the two copy operations.

Comment: Is there a name for the expression syntax that describes what you can put in Inputs/Outputs? This kind of stuff - "@(TXTFile->'%(Filename).content')"? I have always had trouble finding documentation of what is possible in that syntax.

Comment: Yes, it's called an `MSBuild Transform` documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476.aspx

Comment: I achieved my goal by adding a DestFolder metadata item to each file to be copied, so I could have a single input list of files while at the same time using a transform to generate the output paths.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, here's my specific solution XML (using the answer from @jessehouwing):

First: create a single `MySourceFiles` item group with all the files I want to copy, even though I need to copy files into different folders.
Secondly: tag each file item to be copied with a metadata value holding its destination folder: `DestFolder`.

I could then use a transform to generate the list of output paths:

```
@(MySourceFiles->'%(DestFolder)%(Filename)%(Extension)')
```

To specify the Target's Inputs and Outputs, I could use MySourceFiles, and the transform.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DEST>c:\where\to\copy\files\</DEST>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <!-- dlls/pdbs go in DEST\bin -->
  <MySourceFiles Include="$(TargetDir)*.pdb;$(TargetDir)*.dll">
    <DestFolder>$(DEST)bin\</DestFolder>
  </MySourceFiles>
  <!-- anotherfile.txt goes in DEST -->
  <MySourceFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)anotherfile.txt">
    <DestFolder>$(DEST)</DestFolder>
  </MySourceFiles>
</ItemGroup>

<Target 
  Name="CopyFiles" 
  Inputs="@(MySourceFiles)" 
  Outputs="@(MySourceFiles->%(DestFolder)%(Filename)%(Extension))">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(MySourceFiles->'%(DestFolder)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>

<!-- inject target into build process -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>
    $(BuildDependsOn);
    CopyFilesToSDK
  </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```